# In Brackets my end </body> is red, what seems to be the causing this? What is left opened?

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

```
<a href="Services.html">
        <button type="button"class="btn">Book Now!</button>

        <div id="contact">
    <p> <b> Contact us: </b> CapitalExplorers@Wellington.com</p>
</div>
  </body>
```

Trying to find out what is causing the `</body>` to be red. I believe it has something to do with the `<a href` part but not sure. Any ideas on a potential fix?

Comment: you never closed the anchor all the way at the top, this still needs an `</a>`

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried this <a href="Services.html"></a> and the </body> is still red :/

Comment: could you provide the whole code then? i think something else might be missing

Comment: sure https://pastebin.com/YYQKfqmE

Comment: if you have added the `</a>` then your code above is correct, so its somewhere else where it makes the body tag turn red

Comment: looking at your code, you are missing the closing tag of the </head> aswell, something i also notice is that the `<ul>` tags are also not closed. and you are using an id for multiple ul's this is not valid html, as html only wants one element for an id. styling multiple elements at once should be done with a class

Comment: This is why indentation is really important, take care of it to avoid some bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to close your  tag:

```
<head>
    ...
</head>
```

You're missing the closing tag of the first list.

```
<body>

    <ul id="navigation">  
        <li><a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="Bookings.html">Bookings</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services.html"> Services </a></li>
        <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul> <!-- Include here a closing tag -->
```

The `<a>` tag also needs to be closed.

```
    <a href="Services.html">
        <button type="button"class="btn">Book Now!</button>
    </a> <!-- For example, if you want the link only in the button (even if it is not a good practice) -->
    <div id="contact">
        <p><b>Contact us:</b> CapitalExplorers@Wellington.com</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at the provided snippet. i think this is what your html should look like. added some closing tags and removed some spaces.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
   <head>
       <title>Capital Explorers- Home</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo:wght@700&family=Chelsea+Market&family=IBM+Plex+Sans:wght@400;600&family=Lato:wght@300&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

<body> 
         
     <ul id="navigation">  
         <li><a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a></li>
         <li><a href="Bookings.html">Bookings</a></li>
         <li><a href="Services.html"> Services </a></li>
         <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
     </ul>  
                 
    <h1>Capital <span> Explorers </span></h1>
       
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Explore Wellington.</h2>
    </div>
         
    <div id="paragraph"> 
        <p> At Capital Explorers, our mission is to provide Fun, Adventurous and <span> Eco-friendly               </span> Tours of Wellington City and beyond.
        </p>
    </div>
             
    <div id="SubPara">
        <p> <b>- Maori</b> culture and history, Te Papa, The Cable Car and many more!
        <br>      
        <b>- Travel on</b> foot, with scooters or bicycles, and also electric vehicles.
        <br>      
        <b> - Family </b> owned and operated, with over 15 years of experience in the tourism industry.
        <a href="Services.html"></a>
        <button type="button"class="btn">Book Now!</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="contact">
        <p> <b> Contact us:</b> CapitalExplorers@Wellington.com</p> 
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```